# Error passing string variable to method

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to pass a variable to a google visualisation method but it keeps bombing out with an error if I use a variable but works fine if I type the string. What am I missing here?

This works:

```
var filterdata = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
filterdata.setRows(
  filterdata.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, value: 'someval'}])
);
```

This doesn't work:

```
filteredrows = "[{column: 0, value: 'someval'}]";

var filterdata = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
filterdata.setRows(
  filterdata.getFilteredRows(filteredrows)
);
```

The error I'm getting is:

"Uncaught Error: columnFilters must be a non-empty array"

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to build an array / string to pass all the dashboard control states as filter conditions for getfilteredrows(). Below is the code I'm using to build the array. I've also tried to create a string but either way it's not accepted...

```
control_states = [ctrl1.getState(),ctrl2.getState(),ctrl3.getState()];
var filteredrows = {};
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < control_states.length; i++) {
  var picker_state = control_states[i]
  for (var j = 0; j < picker_state.selectedValues.length; j++) {
    filteredrows[cnt] = "column: " + i + ", value: '" + picker_state.selectedValues[j] + "'";
    cnt += 1;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem, thanks to naomik and Krasimir for pointing me in the right direction!

```
control_states = [ctrl1.getState(),ctrl2.getState(),ctrl3.getState()];

var filteredrows = [ ];
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < control_states.length; i++) {
  var picker_state = control_states[i]
  for (var j = 0; j < picker_state.selectedValues.length; j++) {
    filteredrows[cnt] = [ ];
    filteredrows[cnt]["column"] = i;
    filteredrows[cnt]["value"] = picker_state.selectedValues[j];
    cnt += 1;
  };
};

var filterdata = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
filterdata.setRows(
  filterdata.getFilteredRows(filteredrows)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One is JSON, the other is an actual array.

Just write the first line as this

```
var filteredrows = [{column: 0, value: 'someval'}];
```

---

If your `filteredrows` is actually a string and you can't change that, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on it first

```
var filterdata = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
filterdata.setRows(
  filterdata.getFilteredRows(JSON.parse(filteredrows))
);
```

Comment: I tried JSON parse but it still didn't work. I'll edit question to clarify what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the method getFilteredRows accepts a valid array and not a string. I'll suggest to use [*JSON.parse*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before to send the string. I.e. something like:

```
filterdata.getFilteredRows(JSON.parse(filteredrows));
```

Comment: I edited question to give more info as I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Aha ... I see. Then you should definitely use JSON.parse to convert your string to valid JavaScript object. After that you can pass it to the API's method.